# how to include css in view file

Tags: zend-framework

I have included css in view file as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('style/root.css'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('style/reset.css'); ?>" />
```

But it is giving this error ->

```
  <b>Message:</b> Invalid controller specified (style)  </p>
```

in application.ini, I have used this

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/zendtest/public"
resources.view[] = "";
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in any view file (.phtml extension) use something like this for javascript or css:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile('/scripts/jquery.min.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/fg.menu.js');

$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/form.css');
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/css/jquery_ui_theme/jquery-ui.custom.css');
```

Comment: But what is the directory structure for .css and .js files? You say `/scripts/jquery.min.js` but where is this `/script` directory lives? Which one is correct if I use modules with ZF: `Module/views/scripts/js` and `Module/views/scripts/css`? Or `Module/views/js` and `Module/views/css`? Thank you.

Comment: no, css & js go into /application/public/css and /application/public/js

Answer (score 2):

The code bellow worked for me , ( i suppose you have your css file  in 'Public/css/bootstrp.css' ) and paste the line in the head of your View.

`<link href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() . '/css/bootstrap.css'; ?>" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [headLink() view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headlink), that will do exactly what you are looking for.